VBA-Dependent Dynamic Dropdowns
I’m working on an Excel project with three sheets: one is the main sheet, and the other two are data sheets. I need to set up four dropdown menus with specific dependencies. Here’s what I need:
Dropdown in C18 (DelDep):
This dropdown should have two options based on MDR2!A1:B1.
Dropdown in D18 (MDRlist):
This dropdown should depend on the selection in C18:
If A1 is selected in C18, it should show non-empty options from A2:A100.
If B1 is selected, it should show non-empty options from B2:B100.
Users should also be able to manually enter a value in D18.
Dynamic Row Insertion:
When users insert new rows below row 18, these new rows should have the same dropdowns, with the same dependencies.
Dropdown in C26 (LocDep):
This should have six fixed options based on Datasheet2!C1:I1.
Dropdown in D26 (DescDep):
This dropdown should depend on the selection in C26 and follow similar logic to the C18/D18 pair.
Auto-Fill in H26 (HR):
Based on the selections in C26 and D26, cell H26 should automatically be filled with data from Datasheet2.
I wrote a basic setup, but I’m having issues when inserting new lines. The new rows don’t maintain the dropdown dependencies correctly, and H26 doesn't auto-fill in the new rows.
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
Dim location As String
Dim department As String
Dim locationCol As Integer
Dim departmentRow As Integer
Dim hourlyRate As Variant
Dim wsData As Worksheet
Dim wsMain As Worksheet
Dim ws2 As Worksheet
Dim newRow As Long
Dim validOptions As String
Dim i As Long
Static inProcess As Boolean

If inProcess Then Exit Sub
inProcess = True



Set wsData = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Hourly Rates")
Set wsMain = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("CTR1")
Set ws2 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("MDR2")

' Handle changes in LocationDep and DescDep
If Not Intersect(Target, wsMain.Range("C:C")) Is Nothing Or _
   Not Intersect(Target, wsMain.Range("D:D")) Is Nothing Then
    
    If Target.Row >= 26 Then
        newRow = Target.Row

        ' Update DescDep options based on LocationDep
        location = wsMain.Cells(newRow, wsMain.Range("LocationDep").Column).Value
        
        wsMain.Range("A100:A" & wsMain.Rows.Count).ClearContents
        
        If location = wsData.Range("I1").Value Then
            i = 100
            For Each cell In wsData.Range("I3:I26")
                If cell.Value <> "" Then
                    wsMain.Cells(i, 1).Value = wsData.Cells(cell.Row, 1).Value
                    i = i + 1
                End If
            Next cell
        Else
            i = 100
            For Each cell In wsData.Range("A3:A26")
                If cell.Value <> "" Then
                    wsMain.Cells(i, 1).Value = wsData.Cells(cell.Row, 1).Value
                    i = i + 1
                End If
            Next cell
        End If
        
        validOptions = ""
        For Each cell In wsMain.Range("A100:A" & i - 1)
            If cell.Value <> "" Then
                validOptions = validOptions & cell.Value & ","
            End If
        Next cell
        
        If Len(validOptions) > 0 Then
            validOptions = Left(validOptions, Len(validOptions) - 1)
        End If
        
        With wsMain.Cells(newRow, wsMain.Range("DescDep").Column).Validation
            .Delete
            .Add Type:=xlValidateList, AlertStyle:=xlValidAlertStop, Operator:= _
            xlBetween, Formula1:="" & validOptions & ""
            .IgnoreBlank = True
            .InCellDropdown = True
        End With
        
        ' Update HourlyRate based on LocationDep and DescDep
        locationCol = Application.Match(wsMain.Cells(newRow, wsMain.Range("LocationDep").Column).Value, wsData.Range("C1:I1"), 0)
        departmentRow = Application.Match(wsMain.Cells(newRow, wsMain.Range("DescDep").Column).Value, wsData.Range("A3:A26"), 0)

        If Not IsError(locationCol) And Not IsError(departmentRow) Then
            hourlyRate = wsData.Cells(departmentRow + 2, locationCol + 2).Value
            
            If IsEmpty(hourlyRate) Then
                wsMain.Cells(newRow, wsMain.Range("HourlyRate").Column).Value = 0
            Else
                wsMain.Cells(newRow, wsMain.Range("HourlyRate").Column).Value = hourlyRate
            End If
        Else
            wsMain.Cells(newRow, wsMain.Range("HourlyRate").Column).Value = 0
        End If
    End If
End If

' Handle changes in DelDep
If Not Intersect(Target, wsMain.Columns(wsMain.Range("DelDep").Column)) Is Nothing Then
    Call UpdateMDRlist(Target.Row)
End If

' Handle newly inserted rows
If Target.Rows.Count = 1 Then
    If Target.Row > 18 And Target.Row < 27 Then
        Call UpdateMDRlist(Target.Row)
    End If
End If


End Sub

Private Sub UpdateMDRlist(ByVal rowIndex As Long)
Dim wsMain As Worksheet
Dim ws2 As Worksheet
Dim depValue As String

Set wsMain = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("CTR1")
Set ws2 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("MDR2")

depValue = wsMain.Cells(rowIndex, wsMain.Range("DelDep").Column).Value

With wsMain.Cells(rowIndex, wsMain.Range("MDRlist").Column).Validation
    .Delete
    If depValue = ws2.Range("A1").Value Then
        .Add Type:=xlValidateList, AlertStyle:=xlValidAlertStop, Operator:= _
        xlBetween, Formula1:="='MDR2'!A2:A81"
    ElseIf depValue = ws2.Range("B1").Value Then
        .Add Type:=xlValidateList, AlertStyle:=xlValidAlertStop, Operator:= _
        xlBetween, Formula1:="='MDR2'!B2:B81"
    Else
        .Add Type:=xlValidateList, AlertStyle:=xlValidAlertStop, Operator:= _
        xlBetween, Formula1:=""
    End If
    .IgnoreBlank = True
    .InCellDropdown = True
End With

End Sub

I haven't looked at this properly but would using the $ notation for cell addresses help e.g.  Formula1:="='MDR2'!$B$2:$B$81"
